# How to I replace the first character of a string only if it's a space in Mariadb (MySQL)

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-update, substring

So I have a bunch of contacts in a database whose first names begin with a space. I want to replace the first character of all contacts if it's a space with nothing (I mean '').

For now I have:

```
UPDATE contact
SET SUBSTRING(contact.FirstName, 1, 1) = ''
WHERE contact.FirstName LIKE ' %'
```

It says that I have a syntax error and I'm not sure why. Unfortunately I'm not exactly sure how to ask this question so I find nothing online.

What should I do instead? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [LTRIM](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/ltrim/):

```
UPDATE contact
SET FirstName = LTRIM(FirstName)
WHERE FirstName LIKE ' %'
```

Comment: Ok that worked. Thanl you!

Comment: If that worked, mark it as answer, please (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: There's a delay before I can do that, but yes I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

SUBSTRING() is a function, the result of a function is immutable, you cannot assign values to a function, but you can do:

`SET Contact.FirstName = LTRIM(Contact.FirstName)`